# How to display this map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I downloaded a map with a .tif, .tfw, and .xml file. I can't get it to display in QGIS. I used geotifcp -e to create a GeoTIFF. I tried Lambert Conformal Conic since it was mentioned in the .xml. Hard to believe they went to all this trouble and it can't be displayed. Here's the gdalinfo for that file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 1908_Los_Angeles.tif
Size is 7983, 9556
Coordinate System is `'
GeoTransform =
  6462833.328395474, 5.957246541541489, -0.0007774314654930954
  1870935.866542538, 0.009750016400271226, -5.899905081920555
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2008:04:07 10:52:01
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=G4364_L8_1908_H3, 3/31/08, 2:33 PM, 16C, 7992x10656 (0+0), 100%, USE THIS CURVE,  1/40 s, R53.0, G31.5, B63.1

  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS2 Macintosh
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=267
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=267
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 6462833.328, 1870935.867)
Lower Left  ( 6462825.899, 1814556.374)
Upper Right ( 6510390.028, 1871013.701)
Lower Right ( 6510382.598, 1814634.208)
Center      ( 6486607.963, 1842785.037)
Band 1 Block=7983x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=7983x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=7983x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Here's the .tfw:

```
5.9572465415414895
0.0097500164002712261
-0.00077743146549309544
-5.8999050819205552
6462836.3066300284
1870932.9214650057
```

and the .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE metadata SYSTEM "http://hgl.harvard.edu:8080/HGL/html/fgdc-std-001-1998.dtd"><metadata>
  <idinfo>
    <citation>
      <citeinfo>
        <origin>Harvard Map Collection, Harvard College Library</origin>
        <origin>Hamlin, Homer, 1864-1920.</origin>
        <pubdate>200805</pubdate>
        <title>Los Angeles, California, 1908 (Raster Image)</title>
        <geoform>map</geoform>
        <pubinfo>
          <pubplace>Cambridge, Massachusetts</pubplace>
          <publish>Harvard Map Collection, Harvard College Library</publish>
        </pubinfo>
        <onlink>http://hgl.harvard.edu:8080/HGL/jsp/HGL.jsp?action=VColl&amp;VCollName=G4364_L8_1908_H3</onlink>
      </citeinfo>
    </citation>
    <descript>
      <abstract>This layer is a georeferenced raster image of the historic paper map entitled: City of Los Angeles, [by] Homer Hamlin, city engineer. Blueprint published in 1908. Scale [ca. 1:19,000]. 

The image inside the map neatline is georeferenced to the surface of the earth and fit to the California State Plane Zone V Coordinate System NAD83 (in Feet) (Fipszone 0405). All map collar and inset information is also available as part of the raster image, including any inset maps, profiles, statistical tables, directories, text, illustrations, index maps, legends, or other information associated with the principal map. 

This map shows features such as roads, drainage, parks, cemeteries, selected public buildings, and more. 

This layer is part of a selection of digitally scanned and georeferenced historic maps from The Harvard Map Collection as part of the Imaging the Urban Environment project.  Maps selected for this project represent major urban areas and cities of the world, at various time periods.  These maps typically portray both natural and manmade features at a large scale. The selection represents a range of regions, originators, ground condition dates, scales, and purposes.</abstract>
      <purpose>Historic paper maps can provide an excellent view of the changes that have occurred in the cultural and physical landscape.  The wide range of information provided on these maps make them useful in the study of historic geography, and urban and rural land use change.  As this map has been georeferenced, it can be used in a GIS as a source or background layer in conjunction with other GIS data.</purpose>
    </descript>
    <timeperd>
      <timeinfo>
        <sngdate>
          <caldate>1908</caldate>
        </sngdate>
      </timeinfo>
      <current>source map publication date</current>
    </timeperd>
    <status>
      <progress>Complete</progress>
      <update>None planned</update>
    </status>
    <spdom>
      <bounding>
        <westbc>-118.326618</westbc>
        <eastbc>-118.169130</eastbc>
        <northbc>34.133514</northbc>
        <southbc>33.978056</southbc>
      </bounding>
    </spdom>
    <keywords>
      <theme>
        <themekt>LCSH</themekt>
        <themekey>Maps</themekey>
        <themekey>Human settlements</themekey>
        <themekey>Cities and towns</themekey>
        <themekey>Land use</themekey>
        <themekey>Landforms</themekey>
        <themekey>Infrastructure (Economics)</themekey>
        <themekey>Transportation</themekey>
        <themekey>Bodies of water</themekey>
      </theme>
      <theme>
        <themekt>ISO 19115 Topic Category</themekt>
        <themekey>imageryBaseMapsEarthCover</themekey>
      </theme>
      <place>
        <placekt>GNS (NIMA)</placekt>
        <placekey>California</placekey>
        <placekey>Los Angeles</placekey>
      </place>
    </keywords>
    <accconst>None</accconst>
    <useconst>For educational, non-commercial use only.</useconst>
    <ptcontac>
      <cntinfo>
        <cntorgp>
          <cntorg>Harvard Map Collection, Harvard College Library</cntorg>
        </cntorgp>
        <cntpos>Harvard Geospatial Library</cntpos>
        <cntaddr>
          <addrtype>mailing and physical address</addrtype>
          <address>Harvard Map Collection</address>
          <address>Pusey Library</address>
          <address>Harvard University</address>
          <city>Cambridge</city>
          <state>MA</state>
          <postal>02138</postal>
          <country>USA</country>
        </cntaddr>
        <cntvoice>617-495-2417</cntvoice>
        <cntfax>617-496-0440</cntfax>
        <cntemail>hgl_ref@gentoo.harvard.edu</cntemail>
        <hours>Monday - Friday, 9:00 am - 4:00 pm EST-USA</hours>
      </cntinfo>
    </ptcontac>
    <native>ESRI ArcCatalog 9.2</native>
  </idinfo>
  <dataqual>
    <attracc>
      <attraccr>The georeferenced raster is a faithfully reproduced digital image of the original source map. Some differences may be detected between the source graphic used and the raster image due to the RGB values assigned that particular color. The intent is to recreate those colors as near as possible.</attraccr>
    </attracc>
    <complete>Data completeness for raster digital image files reflect content of the source graphic. Features may have been eliminated or generalized on the source graphic due to scale and legibility constraints</complete>
    <posacc>
      <horizpa>
        <horizpar>The horizontal positional accuracy of a raster image is approximately the same as the accuracy of the published source map.  The lack of a greater accuracy is largely the result of the inaccuracies with the original measurements and possible distortions in the original paper map document.  There may also be errors introduced during the digitizing and georeferencing process.  In most cases, errors in the raster image are small compared with sources of error in the original map graphic.  The RMS error for this map is 34.80928 feet.  This value describes how consistent the transformation is between the different control points (links).  The RMS error is only an assessment of the accuracy of the transformation.</horizpar>
      </horizpa>
    </posacc>
    <lineage>
      <srcinfo>
        <srccite>
          <citeinfo>
            <origin>Hamlin, Homer, 1864-1920.</origin>
            <pubdate>1908</pubdate>
            <title>City of Los Angeles</title>
            <geoform>map</geoform>
            <pubinfo>
              <pubplace>Los Angeles</pubplace>
              <publish>S.n.</publish>
            </pubinfo>
            <othercit>1 map : blueprint ; 80 x 72 cm.</othercit>
          </citeinfo>
        </srccite>
        <srcscale>19000</srcscale>
        <typesrc>paper</typesrc>
        <srctime>
          <timeinfo>
            <sngdate>
              <caldate>1908</caldate>
            </sngdate>
          </timeinfo>
          <srccurr>publication date</srccurr>
        </srctime>
        <srccitea>Paper Map</srccitea>
        <srccontr>Source map for raster image</srccontr>
      </srcinfo>
      <procstep>
        <procdesc>Production of this raster image began with the scanning of the paper map on a high-resolution scanner: (Betterlight, Super8K2 scanning back camera and ViewFinder 5.x capture software).  Maps were photographed at a copy stand. A vacuum easel was used to keep the maps flat during photography. The imaging specification was designed to produce detailed "Archival Master" images that, to the extent possible, are faithful reproductions of the originals, and that allow for highly detailed screen reproduction and print reproduction at up 1:1. Images in this collection were processed using Adobe Photoshop.  Color and tonal corrections were made using Adobe Photoshop. Image files were viewed on a calibrated monitor. Editing was performed in an ISO 3664 compliant proofing environment. Master Image files were corrected and archived as TIFF files in the sRGB IEC611966-2.1 color-space. When possible files were batch processed using an "action" script derived from edits applied to match a representative sample.</procdesc>
        <srcused>Paper Map</srcused>
        <procdate>2007-2008</procdate>
        <srcprod>TIFF Map Image</srcprod>
        <proccont>
          <cntinfo>
            <cntorgp>
              <cntorg>Harvard College Library</cntorg>
            </cntorgp>
            <cntpos>Digital Imaging and Photography Group</cntpos>
            <cntaddr>
              <addrtype>mailing and physical address</addrtype>
              <address>D-Level, Room D-30</address>
              <address>Widener Library</address>
              <city>Cambridge</city>
              <state>MA</state>
              <postal>02138</postal>
              <country>USA</country>
            </cntaddr>
            <cntvoice>617-495-2030</cntvoice>
          </cntinfo>
        </proccont>
      </procstep>
      <procstep>
        <procdesc>Using ArcMap 9.2 software, the digital TIFF image was georeferenced to common points located on digital vector shapefiles.  For this image, the following vector shapefiles was used as a base map for reference:  ESRI Data and Maps (2007) : U.S. Detailed Streets (1:100,000). The vector data was projected to the 'NAD 1983 California State Plane Zone V (feet)' coordinate system, and the images were subsequently georeferenced to the same projection.   A world file (.tfwx) and an .aux.xml file were automatically generated and saved in association with the digital TIFF image.  See 'Horizontal Accuracy' for the RMS error of this TIFF image.  

Please note that while the image is stored in 'NAD 1983 California State Plane Zone V (feet)' coordinates, the projection will need to be defined by the user in order to display the image with other projected data and the world file will need to be stored in the same root directory as the image. The digital TIFF image was georeferenced to control points that represent the true ground coordinates of the four corners of the quadrangle.  ESRI's ArcCatalog was used to create a control point shapefile which was populated with latitude and longitude measurements from each quadrangle corner and defined with the NAD83 StatePlane California Zone V (feet) projection.   ArcMap 9.2 software was utilized to georeference the image to the projected control points, and a .tfwx (world file) was generated and saved in association with the digital image.</procdesc>
        <srcused>TIFF Map Image</srcused>
        <procdate>2008</procdate>
        <srcprod>Georeferenced Raster Data</srcprod>
        <proccont>
          <cntinfo>
            <cntorgp>
              <cntorg>Harvard Geospatial Library</cntorg>
            </cntorgp>
            <cntpos>GIS Technician</cntpos>
            <cntaddr>
              <addrtype>mailing and physical address</addrtype>
              <address>Harvard University Library</address>
              <address>Office for Information Systems</address>
              <address>90 Mount Auburn Street</address>
              <city>Cambridge</city>
              <state>MA</state>
              <postal>02138</postal>
              <country>USA</country>
            </cntaddr>
            <cntvoice>617-495-2417</cntvoice>
            <cntfax>617-496-0440</cntfax>
            <cntemail>hgl_ref@gentoo.harvard.edu</cntemail>
            <hours>Monday - Friday, 9:00 am - 4:00 pm EST-USA</hours>
          </cntinfo>
        </proccont>
      </procstep>
    </lineage>
  </dataqual>
  <spdoinfo>
    <direct>Raster</direct>
    <rastinfo>
      <rasttype>Pixel</rasttype>
      <rowcount>9556</rowcount>
      <colcount>7983</colcount>
      <vrtcount>1</vrtcount>
    </rastinfo>
  </spdoinfo>
  <spref>
    <horizsys>
      <planar>
        <mapproj>
          <mapprojn>Lambert Conformal Conic</mapprojn>
          <lambertc>
            <stdparll>34.033333</stdparll>
            <stdparll>35.466667</stdparll>
            <longcm>-118.000000</longcm>
            <latprjo>33.500000</latprjo>
            <feast>6561666.666667</feast>
            <fnorth>1640416.666667</fnorth>
          </lambertc>
        </mapproj>
        <planci>
          <plance>row and column</plance>
          <coordrep>
            <absres>5.958177</absres>
            <ordres>5.908050</ordres>
          </coordrep>
          <plandu>survey feet</plandu>
        </planci>
      </planar>
      <geodetic>
        <horizdn>North American Datum of 1983</horizdn>
        <ellips>Geodetic Reference System 80</ellips>
        <semiaxis>6378137.000000</semiaxis>
        <denflat>298.257222</denflat>
      </geodetic>
    </horizsys>
  </spref>
  <eainfo>
    <overview>
      <eaover>The indexes reference a color palette of RGB values from 0 through 255, representing the color value from the original paper sheet map. The colors on that sheet can represent relief, drainage, vegetation, populated places, cultural features, coastal hydrography, transportation features (roads, railroads, tracks and trails), spot elevations and boundaries. The colors are sometimes explained in a legend that is incorporated into the map inset or collar.</eaover>
      <eadetcit>Not applicable.</eadetcit>
    </overview>
  </eainfo>
  <distinfo>
    <distrib>
      <cntinfo>
        <cntorgp>
          <cntorg>Harvard University Library</cntorg>
        </cntorgp>
        <cntpos>Harvard Geospatial Library</cntpos>
        <cntaddr>
          <addrtype>mailing and physical address</addrtype>
          <address>Office For Information Systems</address>
          <address>90 Mount Auburn Street</address>
          <city>Cambridge</city>
          <state>MA</state>
          <postal>02138</postal>
          <country>USA</country>
        </cntaddr>
        <cntvoice>617-495-2417</cntvoice>
        <cntfax>617-496-0440</cntfax>
        <cntemail>hgl_ref@gentoo.harvard.edu</cntemail>
        <hours>Monday - Friday, 9:00 am - 4:00 pm EST-USA</hours>
      </cntinfo>
    </distrib>
    <resdesc>Downloadable Data</resdesc>
    <distliab>Although this data set has been developed by Harvard University, no warranty expressed or implied is made by the University as to the accuracy of the data and related materials. The act of distribution shall not constitute any such warranty, and no responsibility is assumed by the University in the use of this data, or related materials.</distliab>
    <stdorder>
      <digform>
        <digtinfo>
          <formname>TIFF</formname>
          <filedec>ZIP</filedec>
        </digtinfo>
        <digtopt>
          <onlinopt>
            <computer>
              <networka>
                <networkr>http://hgl.harvard.edu/</networkr>
              </networka>
            </computer>
          </onlinopt>
        </digtopt>
      </digform>
      <fees>None</fees>
    </stdorder>
  </distinfo>
  <metainfo>
    <metd>20080520</metd>
    <metc>
      <cntinfo>
        <cntorgp>
          <cntorg>Harvard Geospatial Library</cntorg>
        </cntorgp>
        <cntpos>Geospatial Resources Cataloger</cntpos>
        <cntaddr>
          <addrtype>mailing and physical address</addrtype>
          <address>Harvard University Library</address>
          <address>Office For Information Systems</address>
          <address>90 Mount Auburn Street</address>
          <city>Cambridge</city>
          <state>MA</state>
          <postal>02138</postal>
          <country>USA</country>
        </cntaddr>
        <cntvoice>617-495-2417</cntvoice>
        <cntfax>617-496-0440</cntfax>
        <cntemail>hgl_ref@gentoo.harvard.edu</cntemail>
        <hours>Monday - Friday, 9:00 am - 4:00 pm EST-USA</hours>
      </cntinfo>
    </metc>
    <metstdn>FGDC Content Standards for Digital Geospatial Metadata</metstdn>
    <metstdv>FGDC-STD-001-1998</metstdv>
    <mettc>local time</mettc>
  </metainfo>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your layer CRS to [epsg:2229](http://epsg.io/2229) which is NAD83/California Zone 5 (USFt). At that point your raster should show up (may be try zoom to layer extent from the right click menu). I gained this knowledge from scanning the XML (metadata file) for the line

> Please note that while the image is stored in 'NAD 1983 California State Plane Zone V (feet)' coordinates, the projection will need to be defined by the user in order to display the image

and then searching on epsg.io for California and assuming that the American fetish for roman numerals applied here :-)

To make life easier next time try adding the following to a `.prj` file:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / California zone 5 (ftUS)",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",35.46666666666667],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",34.03333333333333],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",33.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-118],PARAMETER["false_easting",6561666.667],PARAMETER["false_northing",1640416.667],UNIT["US survey foot",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2229"]]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the answer and also giving the methodology. Will make it easier for me next time.

There was no .prj file. Have to talk to Harvard about that.

Comment: I had georeferenced the original tif using Georeferencet and surprisingly the color (tint and contrast) are different than the file created with geotifcp.